# Como voltar para a página inicial após uma mensagem de alert

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com uma página que realiza um cáculo de IMC e salva algumas informações no banco.

A estrutura está dividida em quatro arquivos: 
`index.html`    = Código html; 
`index.php`     = Chama o `index.html`; 
`banco.php`     = Conecta com o banco de dados; 
`cadastrar.php` = Realiza o cálculo, salva no banco e retorna a mensagem

A mensagem do IMC é dada através de um `alert()`. Quando eu clico em "Ok", o alert fecha e eu continuo na página toda em branco `cadastrar.php` (página que pega os dados, faz o calculo e retorna a mensagem do usuário).

Tentei utilizar a expessão `location.href` e outras opções para tentar redirecionar, mas sem sucesso.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que após eu fechar o `alert()`, o usuário retorne para a página inicial (index)?

```
session_start();
include "banco.php";


$nome = "";
$altura = 0;
$peso = 0;

if(!empty($_POST))
{
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$altura = $_POST['altura'];
$peso = $_POST['peso'];

cadastrar($nome,$altura,$peso);
calcularIMC($altura,$peso);

}


function cadastrar($nome,$altura,$peso)
{
try
{
    $pdo = conectar();
    $incluir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario("
            . "nome, altura, peso) VALUES("
            . ":nome, :altura, :peso)");
    $incluir->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
    $incluir->bindValue(":altura", $altura);
    $incluir->bindValue(":peso", $peso);
    $incluir->execute();

    if($incluir->rowCount() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}catch(PDOException $e)
{
   echo "Erro ao incluir na tabela categoria ".$e->getMessage();
}
}

function calcularIMC($altura,$peso){

$imc = 0;
if($altura >0 && $peso >0){
  $imc = $peso / ($altura * $altura);
}

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Sua quantidade de IMC é: '.$imc.'")';
echo 'location.href="index.html"';  //Tentei utilizar o location.href, mas sem sucesso 
echo '</script>';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta ponto e virgula depois do alert.

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';   
echo 'alert("Sua quantidade de IMC é: '.$imc.'");';
echo 'location.href="index.html";';    
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Fiz esta alteração. O `alert()` não dispara e página também não é redirecionada

Comment: Aqui funciona em vários browsers, eu não testei o código todo, só esse último, dei um valor qualquer a uma variável "$imc" antes do código. Pressione as teclas CTRL+U na página, e verifique se este JavaScript está sendo gerado.

Comment: Aqui não surtiu efeito, mas tenta remover: language="javascript", ou trocar por 'type='text/javascript'

Comment: Quando eu adiciono o `echo 'location.href="index.html";';` ele apresenta o seguinte erro na linha 1 do php: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Você colocou o ";" depois do alert? Se o interpretador não espera o "location" (tradução do erro) é por que ele espera outra coisa antes, que pode bem ser o ponto e vírgula que eu sugeri.

Comment: É incrível, eu sempre consigo fazer o mais difícil e o me bato no mais fácil rsrs Era o ponto e vírgula no alert. Obrigado!